# SharePoint "List does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Okay, so I seem to be the only administrator managing a SharePoint website on behalf of the Health Service. However, being as it's linked to the government, someone made this website for free. I also assume that he made some of the webparts himself.

One of these web parts was an FAQ webpart which enabled you to create FAQs with a fancy format. Usually when I try to make an FAQ I can select it and it will now be ready to edit. Now, however, when I go to modify it, it will take me to an Error Page which says:

"List does not exist

The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services."

Does anyone know how to find out what the webpart is looking for or what the list is called so I can make another one to replace it? I tried looking in the ".Aspx" for the page but it doesn't keep any information on the webpart. Any ideas or pointers would be very grateful.

Below is some Web Part code from the FAQ.webpart file located in the designer website.

```
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type         name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart,         Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,         PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData> <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="FilterType3" type="string" />
        <property name="PageSize" type="int">-1</property>
        <property name="SortBy" type="string">{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}</property>
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ContentTypeBeginsWithId" type="string" />
        <property name="ServerTemplate" type="string">100</property>
        <property name="Height" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterField2" type="string" />
        <property name="SystemViewFields" type="string" />
        <property name="ParameterBindings" type="string" />
        <property name="FeedTitle" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ContentTypeName" type="string" />
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="DisplayColumns" type="int">1</property>
        <property name="XslLink" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="GroupBy" type="string" />
        <property name="DataSourcesString" type="string" />
        <property name="WebUrl" type="string">/sites/cerner</property>
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AdditionalGroupAndSortFields" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="FeedDescription" type="string" />
        <property name="WebsOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">Title,Text;Answer,Note;SME,Text</property>
        <property name="DisplayName" type="string" />
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
        <property name="AdditionalFilterFields" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="NoDefaultStyle" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterValue3" type="string" />
        <property name="BaseType" type="string" />
        <property name="FireInitialRow" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="SortByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
        <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
        <property name="GroupStyle" type="string">DefaultHeader</property>
        <property name="DataColumnRenames" type="string" />
        <property name="HeaderXslLink" type="string">/Sites/cerner/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/FAQHeader.xsl</property>
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ViewFieldsOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterField1" type="string" />
        <property name="UseCache" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ShowUntargetedItems" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
        <property name="DataSourceID" type="string" />
        <property name="ListName" type="string">FAQ</property>
        <property name="FilterType1" type="string" />
        <property name="Default" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterType2" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="ViewFlag" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterOperator3" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="FilterOperator2" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Eq</property>
        <property name="GroupByFieldType" type="string" />
        <property name="UseCopyUtil" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Use to display a dynamic view of content from your site on a web page</property>
        <property name="Filter1ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
        <property name="ItemLimit" type="int">15</property>
        <property name="SortByFieldType" type="string">DateTime</property>
        <property name="ListGuid" type="string">A72FB448-BAC3-4661-BEAB-F435E441AA1D</property>
        <property name="ViewContentTypeId" type="string" />
        <property name="ItemXslLink" type="string">/Sites/cerner/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/FAQItemStyle.xsl</property>
        <property name="FeedEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="MainXslLink" type="string">/Sites/cerner/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/NHSContentQueryMain.xsl</property>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="Filter2ChainingOperator" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterChainingOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Or</property>
        <property name="FilterValue1" type="string" />
        <property name="ListsOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="GroupByDirection" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+SortDirection, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">Desc</property>
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
        <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" />
        <property name="UseSQLDataSourcePaging" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Width" type="string" />
        <property name="FilterByAudience" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="FilterValue2" type="string" />
        <property name="SampleData" type="string">&lt;dsQueryResponse&gt;                 &lt;Rows&gt;                     &lt;Row Title="Item 1" LinkUrl="http://Item1" Group="Group Header" __begincolumn="True" __begingroup="True" /&gt;                     &lt;Row Title="Item 2" LinkUrl="http://Item2" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;                     &lt;Row Title="Item 3" LinkUrl="http://Item3" __begincolumn="False" __begingroup="False" /&gt;                 &lt;/Rows&gt;                 &lt;/dsQueryResponse&gt;</property>
        <property name="Xsl" type="string">&lt;xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x" &gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /&gt; &lt;xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl" /&gt; &lt;/xsl:stylesheet&gt;</property>
        <property name="CacheXslStorage" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Title" type="string">FAQ Content Web Part</property>
        <property name="ShowWithSampleData" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="CacheXslTimeOut" type="int">86400</property>
        <property name="ItemStyle" type="string">NoImage</property>
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="FilterField3" type="string" />
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string"></property>
      </properties>
    </data>
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Please share the ULS logs ..It will help us narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 3):

There could be seevral reasons for this:

- Please go to the list, check the permission settings, make sure you
  have permission to the list.
- Can you access the list directly using the URL?
- You can find the list using the list GUID, type the this URL in browser: `http://yourserver/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List={ceb31d57-dea6-4524-ba47-bf15f6f73d4a}`, it will go to the list settings page and you can check the list settings.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the markup, It is content query webpart. 
It is looking for a list with GUID  set in below property.

```
<property name="ListGuid" type="string">A72FB448-BAC3-4661-BEAB-F435E441AA1D</property>
```

The list should be under site with URL set in below property:

```
<property name="WebUrl" type="string">/sites/cerner</property>
```

Better, you create a new list in that site and update the GUID.

To find column names, Open the xsl in sharepoint designer or notepad from the path in below property and look  for all `<xsl:value-of select="{column names}" />` :

```
<property name="ItemXslLink" type="string">/Sites/cerner/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/FAQItemStyle.xsl</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to try quickly, that worked to resolve my problem. *It took me many hours to find a fix for this problem. No single article covered all the hoops I had to jump through to resolve this.* It was not an obvious fix. It will only cost you a couple minutes of your time to try and if you *take screenshots before making the change*, it will be easy to revert your selections and there are no major repercussions.

1) **Login** to your SharePoint 2013 page any way possible where you can eventually get to the *Site Settings* of the *site* where your *page* is giving you the "*List does not exist*" error.

> You may have to log in to a subsite and then work your way up to the Top Level Site or vice versa; login to Top Level and go to Site Contents where you will see links to your subsites at the bottom.

2) Click on the **gear icon** at the top right of the *page* and select **Site Settings**.

3) Under *Look and Feel* select **Master Page** and *change* the current *master page selections* to one of the defaults, like **seattle** or *oslo*.

4) Click **OK** to save.

5) Refresh your page that's getting the "*List does not exist*" error.

If it worked, you're blessed! If not, I guess you'll just have to keep digging until the lightbulb turns on.

Hopefully this helps someone who just wants a simple answer instead of the numerous iterations it took me to get this figured out. This solution is nowhere else that I have found. I did go through all the other suggestions in this site and more.

If anyone is interested I can explain why this happened.

*I'm using IE 11 on Windows 10.*

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that one of the web parts is broken. If you have problems with a Web Part, append ?contents=1 to the end of the URL syntax (http://siteurl/default.aspx?contents=1), and then press Enter. This opens the Web Part Maintenance page where you can remove and repair the broken Web Part. These errors indicate that the Web Part was not installed or was configured incorrectly for the new environment and must be reinstalled or reconfigured.

Update and redeploy any Web Parts that exist but no longer function correctly.

Answer was here and it worked perfectly for me!

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customized-files-found-during-site-collection-health-check-d2621cc5-d9a3-45f9-aa1b-eca4fb462485