# Migrate Dataview webparts in Sp2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration

I'm trying to migrate the Dataview webparts which are in one of the sub site page to another subsite in same site collection through export and import option and the data is pointing to the root site list, but I'm getting the message "List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.It may have been deleted by another user" when adding the imported webpart.

Any suggestions/help?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a refernce to the answers in the following posts: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/df92a664-45a3-4b14-8b8a-240fbc06b1b6/list-does-not-exist-the-page-you-selected-contains-a-list-that-does-not-exist-it-may-have-been?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

[SharePoint "List does not exist"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39365/sharepoint-list-does-not-exist)